# Using Promises with readdir to diplay directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I know that there are better ways to do this and tools such as serve-index already exist as an npm package to list a directory structure, but I wanted to test this out on my as I am still rather new to using Node.js and JavaScript.

Currently, my code is as follows, and I am confused as to why my array is empty.

```
let directoryTree = [];    
let directoryList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    resolve(fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '..'), (err, fileList) => { 
        for (file of fileList) {
            console.log(file);
            directoryTree.push(file);
        }
    }));

}).then(() =>  console.log(directoryTree))
  .catch((err) => console.log(error));
```

What gets displayed is

```
[]
app
files
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
```

This indicates to me that the promise is being resolved before readdir finishes executing, otherwise the empty array wouldn't be logged first. I believe that something may be incorrect in my usage of promises then, but I might be wrong. I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `resolve()` to resolve the promise when the callback is done fetching the data asynchronously.

Then when the data is *fetched* and *resolved* you would get the list of files in the `then()` callback:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '..'), (err, fileList) => { 
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(fileList); //resolve with list of files
    });
})
.then((list) =>  console.log(list))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Promise` incorrectly.

The syntax is (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise)):

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do something asynchronous which eventually calls either:
  //
  resolve(someValue); // fulfilled
  // or
  reject("failure reason"); // rejected
});
```

Refactoring:

```
let directoryList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '..'), (err, fileList) => { 
    if (err) reject(err)
    else resolve(fileList)
  });
})
// directoryList is a Promise that could reject or resolve
directoryList.then(() =>  console.log(directoryTree))
.catch((err) => console.log(error));
```